# SQL selecting records with view

Tags: sql

How to solve this?

I have a tables `A,B,C` and view from C

- Table A has a1,a2,a3 etc.
- Table C has c1,c2,c3 etc.

Table B has

```
(a1,c1)
(a1,c4)
(a1,c3)
(a2,c1)
(a2,c3)
(a2,c4)
(a3,c1)
(a3,c4)
(a4,c1)
(a4,c4)
(a4,c3)
(a4,c5)
```

Examples:

I have View C with c1,c3,c4

Result should be: a1, a2, a4

Or:

View C: c1, c5

Result should be: a4

I want all the elements (aX) from table B that have all the elements in the view C.

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use?

Comment: If view C has (c1,c5), why would a3 be included in the result?  It has c1 and c4, but not c5.

Comment: @MarkLeiber your are right, I edited it.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I use MySQL. Is there no plain SQL solution?

Comment: MySQL is the product, SQL is the language. There's no such thing as 'plain SQL' although modern products have no problem with simple joins. Have you tried a join between B and C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
create table temp_a (
  a_rec varchar2(2)
);

create table temp_b (
  a_rec varchar2(2),
  c_rec varchar2(2)
);

create table temp_c (
  c_rec varchar2(2)
);

insert into temp_a values ('a1');
insert into temp_a values ('a2');
insert into temp_a values ('a3');
insert into temp_a values ('a4');

insert into temp_c values ('c1');
insert into temp_c values ('c3');
insert into temp_c values ('c4');

insert into temp_b values ('a1','c1');
insert into temp_b values ('a1','c4');
insert into temp_b values ('a1','c3');
insert into temp_b values ('a2','c1');
insert into temp_b values ('a2','c3');
insert into temp_b values ('a2','c4');
insert into temp_b values ('a3','c1');
insert into temp_b values ('a3','c4');
insert into temp_b values ('a4','c1');
insert into temp_b values ('a4','c4');
insert into temp_b values ('a4','c3');
insert into temp_b values ('a4','c5');

select b.a_rec
from temp_b b 
join temp_c c on c.c_rec = b.c_rec
group by a_rec
having count(*) >= (select count(c_rec) from temp_c);
```

Note that if you have View C with c1,c3,c4, then the result will actually be: a1, a2, a4 (since a1 also meets the criteria).